# How to use srtftime in views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am getting an error with `strftime`.

My views look like:

`<%=room.date%>` which works and yields "2017-07-27".

However, I want to convert this to "July 27, 2017".

`<%= Date.parse(room.date).strftime("%B %e, %Y ") %>` does not work and causes the following error:

> ActionView::Template::Error (no implicit conversion of Date into
>   String)

My schema is:

```
t.date     "date"
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `room.date` is type of date you shouldn't try to parse it. So I'd suggest first try to use `<%= room.date.strftime('%B %e, %Y')`. Please  comment below if that wont work.

Answer (score 3):

Just to throw a different hat into the ring, you can also use

```
<%= l room.date, format: :long %>
```

which, by default, uses `"%B %d, %Y"` but can be easily changed by adding into your `config/locales/en.yml`.

```
en:
  date:
    formats:
      long: "%B %e, %Y"
  time:
    formats:
      long: "%B %e, %Y"
```

Use `date:` if it's a `Date` object or `time:` if it's `DateTime` or `Time`. This is short for `I18n.l` and looks like it works as far back a [rails 3.2.13](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/i18n.html#adding-date-time-formats) at the least (it's hard to tell which rails you're using).

This way, if you ever want to support different locales the dates are all set up for it and, probably more importantly, it moves the date format out of your views, so if you ever decide you want a different format (`"%A %B %e, %Y"`, for instance) you can change it in one place and all the views displaying dates get updated.

Note: If it is a `Time` or `DateTime` you might want to use instead

```
<%= l room.date, format: :date %>
```

and in `config/locales/en.yml`

```
en:
  time:
    formats:
      date: "%B %e, %Y"
```

so your `format: :long` still shows the time portion when you want it to

Answer (score 1):

It's asking for a String instead a Date data type, pass it a String, try with:

```
Date.parse(room.date.to_s).strftime("%B %e, %Y")
```

Comment: The error did not appear anymore, but the date was not displayed. Not sure why.

Comment: If you need to print such value in the view, then you can use just `room.date.strftime("%B %e, %Y ")` as @knut has mentioned, give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

When `room.date` is a date, why do you want to parse it? You could use the Date directly.

Can you try:

```
<%= room.date.strftime("%B %e, %Y ") %>
```